# How to split a string on whatever number of spaces, but also keep them all?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `"a b  c   d"` (note the increasing number of spaces) and I would like to get it split as: `["a ", "b  ", "c   ", "d"]`.

I have seen the usage of look-behind, but it does not seem to work if the expected delimiter is potentially made of multiple characters, e..g, this does not work:

`String[] parts = text.split("(?<=([\\s]+))");`

as it returns the extra white spaces after the first as separate matches, that is, it returns `["a ", "b ", " ", "c ", " ", " ", "d"]`.

Is there a way to do it in a one liner, or do I have to merge back the extra spaces in post processing?

Comment: Is the length of "letter" part is fixed? Like 1 in your example?

Comment: Try `String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)");`

Comment: Wicktor, yes, that works!

Comment: Wicktor, I'd suggest to turn that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `split` use following for matching in a `matcher.find()` loop:

```
\S+\s*|\s+
```

This regex matches one or more non-whitespace characters followed by zero or more whitespaces.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u4ZoTv/5)

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "\\S+\\s*|\\s+";
final String string = "a b  c   d";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add( matcher.group(0) );
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping for a one liner but this one does the trick too. I had to alter the regex a bit because I can also have spaces at the beginning, this one seems to work "\\S+\\s*|\\s+". If you edit the answer accordingly I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually Victor suggestion works and it's a one liner!

Comment: I have modified the answer as per your comment. Also look around regex will also work but that comes with a cost. This regex takes just 14 steps to find a match.